# Calculating transitions at solution level

Tags: java, optaplanner

In my scheduling problem, I have to calculate on each move the number of transitions of a variable located in the planning entities.

This variable reflects the state of the system and can be viewed, in the examination problem, as computing the number of times a room changes from used to unused.

This computation is really difficult to describe in Drools so I wanted to find another way. I tried to use `@ProblemFactCollectionProperty` on a method at the solution class level but it doesn't seem to be called enough to compute the transitions accurately.

Is `@ProblemFactCollectionProperty` on method, as with *TopicConflict* computation in *Examination* example, the good way to implement this or is there another way ?

Of course, the goal behind this is to minimize the number of transitions.

**EDIT**

When is such a `@ProblemFactCollectionProperty` method called ? At planning solution cloning or each time I access the facts in the Drools rules ?

Comment: Maybe shadow variables might be of use - then the drools rules can just work on top of those.

Comment: I thought about it but my question is then whether I can put a shadow variable in the `@PlanningSolution` class as it aggregates the state of each `@PlanningEntity` objects ? The second question is in my updated question.

Comment: It should work, but I wouldn't put a shadow variable in the planning solution for design reasons: just create a new class and add it as a singleton in the planning solution with a @PlanningEntityProperty (without the word "Collection" in there).

Comment: So, I need to create it with an attribute pointing at my entities list in order to perform the computation each time it's needed in my rules. Am I right ?

Comment: There's still something I don't get. My transitions insertions don't have to be computed each time a state variable changes in my Planning entity but only once, just before score calculation is initiated as its the state of the current solution. Wouldn't it be more interesting to call these insertions in a overriden calculateScore method of the ScoreDirector class instead of using a shadow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `@ProblemFactCollectionProperty` method is called during `solvingStarted()`, not during planning cloning nor during score calculations.

It's needed for Drools/ConstraintStreams score calculation, but only once (in single-threaded, non-repeated solving at least), to fill the working facts.

Planning cloning doesn't impact the score calculation, because it clones from the working solution to a new best solution (so the working solution isn't modified and the score director doesn't notice it).